# Readline infinitely while handling async console logs in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a script where you can write commands:

```js
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
})

let askCommands = async () => {
  readline.question('> ', async (command) => {
    // If user exits close readline
    if(command === 'exit') {
      readline.close();
      return process.exit();
    }
    switchCommands(command);
    askCommands();
  })
}

let switchCommands = (command) => {
  if(command === 'test') {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Hello!')
    }, 1000)
  } else {
    console.log(`Invalid command '${command}'`)
  }
}

askCommands();
```

It works fine until I use an async `console.log()`. This is because the script writes the async outputs without removing the `'> '` and then generates a new line that does not have the `'> '`. Moreover, if in this new line you write any character and then delete it the `'> '` is added automatically.

I would like to write async logs without having the `'> '` before them and without removing the `'> '` where users write the commands. Is there any easy solution to this problem?

Comment: just \r and then over-write the '> ' and then re-write it on a new line?

Comment: @0xLogN Yes, but `console.log` doesn't do that by default. Also, this still will conflict with a user typing while the `console.log` is called.